# Creating json in loop

Tags: javascript, json

I'm just starting with javascript. I can't create JSON message dynamically. 
I have this structure:

```
one: {
    two: {
        $: {
                three: "ttt"
        },
        four: {
            five: "xxx",
            six: "yyy",
            seven: "zzz"
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a function generating this json. `one`, `two`, `$`, `three` are constants. My function should get array of `four` structure and create json with many `four` structure. How to do that?

Comment: How about build the object as you want it and then use `JSON.stringify(myObject);` however, is it the actually JSON string you want, or are you asking how to build an object? You want a list of something,then use an array and `push()` each item in to that array

Answer (score 0):

Just create it as a JavaScript object and then stringify it (if you need to) JSON is native to JavaScript (JavaScript Object Notation = JSON). See this [reference](http://json.org/).

```
var one = {
    two: {
        $: {
            three: "ttt"
        },
        four: {
            five: "xxx",
                six: "yyy",
                seven: "zzz"
        }
    }
};

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(one);
```

EDIT: to generate data dynamically you could use a forEach loop:

```
var one = {
    two: {
        $: {
            three: "ttt"
        }
    }
};

var arr = ['three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

arr.forEach(function (item) {
    one[item] = {
        item1: "xxx",
        item2: "yyy",
        item3: "zzz"
    };
});

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(one);
console.log(jsonString);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot that part. Updated answer. Thanks